# SVN checkout error E720006: Error running context

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

During checkout:

```
svn.exe checkout https://IPv4:40443/svn/project
```

An error occurs:

```
svn: E720006: Error running context: Nieprawidłowe dojście.
```

It's in polish language and it could be translated as (I hope):

```
...context: the handle is invalid
```

Is this error related with network connection or any Windows IO restriction?

I'm working on Windows 7, which is very restricted by administrator. So here everything could be blocked or limited.

The same checkout from "normal" computer works great. So where to search for problem? Disk? Network settings?

Comment: What server do you use? What is its version? What client version do you use? This information is important.

Comment: SVN server was created by SubversionEdge. `svn.exe` is taken from latest TortoiseSVN 1.9.7. Unfortunately, I don't remember more... I'll write more details on Monday.